# Why doesn't the Swift language require semicolons?

Tags: ios, swift

In Swift we can use a semicolon that will not show you any error. Even when you don't use it, it wouldn't show any error. So, is there a bug in Swift or is that a kind of facility for the user?

Comment: Same as Scala. This compiler can figure it out most of the time, so they aren't necessary.

Answer (score 7):

From the documentation:

> Unlike many other languages, Swift does not require you to write a
>   semicolon (;) after each statement in your code, although you can do
>   so if you wish. Semicolons are required, however, if you want to write
>   multiple separate statements on a single line:

Comment: in case of: var a = 5, b = true; b = false

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: where did you saw a question? It was the extend.

Answer (score 4):

In Swift "semicolon is optional" if you are writing single line.
And the "semicolon is required" for writing multiple statements in the same line.

Example:

```
var myString = "Hello, World"; println(myString)
```

If you write single statement with semicolon at the end, the compiler wouldn't warn or complain.